# Why Datetime.ParseExact doesn't work

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I am trying to parse the following `09/04/2015 17:22:29.183 PM`

The code is as follows:

```
string s = "09/04/2015 17:22:29.183 PM";
DateTime.ParseExact(s,Constants.DateTimeFormat,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The `DateTimeFormat` is of the form `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt`

However the compiler throws up the error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please provide the actual error.  It doesn't look like the _compiler_ would throw an error in this case, but rather there might be a _runtime_ error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier) is for [12-hour clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) format which takes `01` to `12`, you need to use [`HH` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#HH_Specifier) which is for [24-hour clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) format which takes `00` to `23`.

```
string s = "09/04/2015 17:22:29.183 PM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.Dump(); // 09.04.2015 17:22:29
}
```

But on the other hand, AM or PM designators are for 12-hour clock format. That's why there is no such a thing as 17 PM or 17 AM.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `HH` instead of `hh`.

Of course, it's a bit weird to use `HH` *and* `tt` at the same time. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: heh; think of it like parity checking ;p if you get "...17:22:29.183 AM" you know there's a problem ;p